# What's are practical example where acquire release memory order differs from sequential consistency?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic, memory-model

Clearly, sequential consistent atomic operations differ in their valid observable behavior from acquire-release only operations in a valid C++ program. Definitions are given in the C++ standard (since C++11) or [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order).

However, I have never come across a real-world example of an algorithm or a data structure that where acquire-release semantics is insufficient and sequential consistency is needed.

What would be an **practical** example of a real world algorithm or data structure, where sequential consistency is needed and acquire-release memory order is not enough?

Note, that even [`std::mutex` does not guarantee sequential consistency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41847511/is-stdmutex-sequentially-consistent).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Peterson's algorithm is an example of something that requires sequential consistency.

In the days before mutexes, the algoritm was used to give a single thread access to a protected area.
The algoritm only works with 2 threads, each managing a flag that expresses the intention to access the protected area.
If both set the flag at (about) the same time, both will backoff and try again.
The real algorithm is more advanced since it uses a 'turn' flag to manage fair access, but to show the difference between seq/cst and acq/rel this is not necessary.

Below is a ready-to-compile, simplified version of the Peterson algorithm that actually shows that the algoritms is broken if something weaker than sequential consistency is used.
Interestingly enough, this is broken even on X86 since that platform allows store-loads to be reordered.
The problem with store-load reordering is that both threads may express their intention to access the protected area by setting their `me` flag to `true`, while both are reading `false` from the `him` flag (since the value was not propagated yet to both threads) and enter the protected area. This is not possible with sequential consistency.

With `gcc`, I had to compile with `-O3` optimizations to have the `assert` fire, with `clang` that was not necessary.
Both compilers use a different approach to implement sequential consistency.

```
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <assert.h>

std::atomic<bool> flag1{false};
std::atomic<bool> flag2{false};

std::atomic<int> counter{0};

// Change these to memory_order_seq_cst to fix the algorithm
static const auto store_ordering = std::memory_order_release;
static const auto load_ordering  = std::memory_order_acquire;

void busy(int n)
{
    auto &me  = (n==1) ? flag1 : flag2;
    auto &him = (n==1) ? flag2 : flag1;

    for (;;)
    {
        for (;;)
        {
            me.store(true, store_ordering);
            if (him.load(load_ordering) == false)
            {
                // got the 'lock'
                break;
            }

            // retention, no wait period -> busy loop
            me.store(false, store_ordering);
        }

        int tmp = counter.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
        assert(tmp == 0);

        /*
         * critical area
         */

        tmp = counter.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
        assert(tmp == 1);

        me.store(false, store_ordering);
    }
}


int main()
{
    std::thread t1{busy, 1};
    std::thread t2{busy, 2};

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

Comment: You should use memory_order_seq_cst on fetch_add and fetch_sub since it makes the example clearer, and keeps the bug in.

Comment: @2501 `counter` is not part of the algorithm but only used as a state variable to prove that 1 thead at a time can enter. Hence it has no relationship with any data and therefore I used `relaxed` on the 2 RMW operations. You are right that seq/cst would still make the example valid.