# Difference btw atomic exchange (without return val) and store? It's about Peterson algorithm with atomic lib

Tags: c++, atomic

```
std::atomic<int> flag0(0),flag1(0),turn(0);

void lock(unsigned index)
{
    if (0 == index)
    {
        flag0.store(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
        turn.exchange(1, std::memory_order_acq_rel);
        //turn.store(1)

        while (flag1.load(std::memory_order_acquire)
            && 1 == turn.load(std::memory_order_relaxed))
            std::this_thread::yield();
    }
    else
    {
        flag1.store(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
        turn.exchange(0, std::memory_order_acq_rel);
        //turn.store(0)

        while (flag0.load(std::memory_order_acquire)
            && 0 == turn.load(std::memory_order_relaxed))
            std::this_thread::yield();
    }
}

void unlock(unsigned index)
{
    if (0 == index)
    {
        flag0.store(0, std::memory_order_release);
    }
    else
    {
        flag1.store(0, std::memory_order_release);
    }
}
```

turn.exchange(0) without left (using like void return function) works similarly to 'turn.store(0)'.

Is there any reason for using 'exchange' method?

In this algorithm, this code doesn't need to save previous value.

Comment: You can use `exchange` as a replacement for load or store, but it still requires the same ordering parameter in the C++ memory model. Peterson's algorithm works with plain loads and stores and since mutual exclusion is based on the order in which multiple variables are modified (and observed by both threads), it's imperative that there is a single total order on those operations.. hence sequential consistency on all operations.

Comment: Without sequential consistency, the algorithm is broken, [even on X86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41858540/whats-are-practical-example-where-acquire-release-memory-order-differs-from-seq/41859912#41859912)

Answer (score 2):

The main difference is than on x86 exchange translates to a `lock xchg` instruction which is *sequentially consistent*, even tough you specified it as `std::memory_order_acq_rel`! If you were to use a store with `std::memory_order_release`, the internal store buffer would spoil your mutual exclusion guarantee (i.e., your lock would be broken)!. However, if you use a store with `std::memory_order_seq_cst`, many compiler will simply translate it to `lock xchg` as well, so you end up with the same machine code.

That said, you should **NOT** rely on the fact that exchange is *implicitly* sequentially consistent. Instead you should specify the C++ memory orders as required, to ensure your code behaves correctly with respect to the C++ standard.

**UPDATE**
There exist various definitions of sequential consistency that try to explain the same idea it in different terms.
Leslie Lamport described it as follows:

> ... the result of any execution is the same as if the operations of all the processors were executed in some sequential order, and the operations of each individual processor appear in this sequence in the order specified by its program."

The C++ standard provides the following definition:

> There shall be a single total order *S* on all `memory_order_seq_cst` operations, consistent with the "happens before" order and modification orders for all affected locations, such that each `memory_order_seq_cst`
>   operation *B* that loads a value from an atomic object *M* observes one of the following values:
>
> - (3.1) the result of the last modification A of M that precedes *B* in *S*, if it exists, or
> - (3.2) if *A* exists, the result of some modification of *M* that is not `memory_order_seq_cst` and that does not happen before *A*, or
> - (3.3) if *A* does not exist, the result of some modification of *M* that is not `memory_order_seq_cst`.

Essentially what this means is that if the exchange and the load operations are both sequentially consistent, then they are strictly ordered in the total order *S* - so either the exchange is ordered before the load or vice versa. If the exchange is ordered before the load, then the load is guaranteed to see the value stored by the exchange (or some later value if such exists). If you have a store that is not sequentially consistent, you do *not* have such a guarantee, i.e., in this case it could happen that both threads succeed in acquiring the lock, simple because they did not "see" the value stored by the other thread.

The x86 memory model is very strong, and every lock prefixed instruction is sequentially consistent. That's why in many cases you don't even notice that your code does not enforce the necessary happens before relations if you are running on a x86 CPU. But things wouldn't run as smoothly if you were to run it on ARM or Power.

Comment: "_lock xchg instruction which is sequentially consistent_" what do you mean by that?

Comment: @curiousguy I have updated my answer to provide more details about sequential consistency.

Answer (score 1):

*[Replacing a previous answer.]*

The original question was "*Is there any reason for using 'exchange' method?*".  And the short answer is: no, there is no good reason for it, in fact `turn.store(1)` is more correct.

But even with `turn.store(1)` I think what you have is almost entirely **not** valid C++.

So here is a longer answer...

---

**In Search of a Correct Implementation of Peterson's Algorithm**

Peterson's Algorithm will work if all loads/stores of `flag0`, `flag1` and `turn` are *memory_order_seq_cst*, thus:

```
std::atomic<int> flag0(0),flag1(0),turn(0);

void lock(unsigned index)
{
    if (0 == index)
    {
        flag0.store(1, std::memory_order_seq_cst) ;
        turn.store(1, std::memory_order_seq_cst) ;
        while (flag1.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst)
                          && (1 == turn.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst)))
            std::this_thread::yield();
    }
    else
    {
        flag1.store(1, std::memory_order_seq_cst) ;
        turn.store(0, std::memory_order_seq_cst) ;
        while (flag0.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst)
                          && (0 == turn.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst)))
            std::this_thread::yield();
    }
}

void unlock(unsigned index)
{
    if (0 == index)
      flag0.store(0, std::memory_order_seq_cst) ;
    else
      flag1.store(0, std::memory_order_seq_cst) ;
}
```

[Of course, `std::memory_order_seq_cst` is the default -- but it does no harm to be explicit... leaving aside the clutter.]

Peterson's Algorithm works provided that **from the perspective of thread 1**:

1. `flag0 = true` *happens-before* `turn = 1` (in `lock()`) in thread 0
2. thread 1 reads the most recent value of `turn` written by it or thread 0
3. `turn = 1` *happens-before* `flag0 = false` (in `unlock()`) in thread 0
4. `flag0 = false` (in `unlock()`) *happens-before* `flag0 = true` (in `lock()`) in thread 0

And vice-versa for thread 0.  In short, (i) all the stores must *inter-thread-happen-before* each other, and (ii) the loads must read the most recent values written to shared memory.

These conditions are met if all these operations are *_seq_cst*.

Of course, *_seq_cst* is (generally) expensive.  So the question is, can any of these operations be weakened ?

The Standard (as I understand it):

1. gets very twitchy about mixing *_seq_cst* operations on a variable with any other memory-order operations on that variable -- as in "do that and you are on your own, sunshine".

   So, if one of the operations on any of `flag0`, `flag1` or `turn` is *_seq_cst*, then all of the operations on that variable should be *_seq_cst* -- to stay within the Standard.
2. says that all *_seq_cst* atomic operations on all variables appear to all threads to happen in the same order -- hence their use above.

   BUT says nothing about not-*_seq_cst* atomic operations (far less not-atomic ones) appearing in any particular order wrt to the *_seq_cst* operations.

   So, if `turn`, say, is loaded/stored *_seq_cst* but `flag0` and `flag1` are not, then  the Standard does not specify the relative order of the stores of `turn` and `flag0` as seen by thread 1, or of `turn` and `flag1` as seen by thread 0.

[If I have not properly understood the Standard, someone please correct me !]

As far as I can tell, this means that all the operations on `turn`, `flag0` and `flag1` are required, by the Standard, to be *_seq_cst*...

...unless we use *_seq_cst* fence instead.

---

**A job for *memory_order_seq_cst* fence ?**

Suppose we recast to use fences, thus:

```
void lock(unsigned index)
{
    if (0 == index)
    {
        flag0.store(1, std::memory_order_relaxed) ;
        std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_release) ;  // <<<<<<<<<<<< (A)
        turn.store(1, std::memory_order_relaxed) ;
        std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_seq_cst) ;  // <<<<<<<<<<<< (B)
        while (flag1.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)
                          && (1 == turn.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)))
            std::this_thread::yield() ;
    }
    else
    {
        flag1.store(1, std::memory_order_relaxed) ;
        std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_release) ;  // <<<<<<<<<<<< (A)
        turn.store(0, std::memory_order_relaxed) ;
        std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_seq_cst) ;  // <<<<<<<<<<<< (B)
        while (flag0.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)
                          && (0 == turn.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)))
            std::this_thread::yield() ;
    }
}

void unlock(unsigned index)
{
    if (0 == index)
      flag0.store(0, std::memory_order_relaxed) ; ;
    else
      flag1.store(0, std::memory_order_relaxed) ; ;
}
```

The *_release* fence (A) after the store of `flagX` means that it will be visible to the other thread before the store of `turn`.  The *_seq_cst* fence (B) after the store of `turn` means (i) that it become visible to the other thread after `flagX` is set true and before `flagX` is set false, and (ii) that any load of `turn` which follows the fence in either thread will see the latest store of `turn` -- *_seq_cst*-wise.

The store of `flagX` in `unlock()` will *happen-before* the next store of `flagX` in `lock()` -- every atomic object has its own *modification-order*.

So, I believe this works, per the Standard, with the minimum of memory-order magic.

Is the *_release* fence (A) really required ?  I believe the answer to that is yes -- that fence is required to ensure the *inter-thread-happens-before* ordering of the stores of `flagX` and `turn`.

Could the *_seq_cst* fence (B) also be *_release* ?  I believe the answer to that is no -- that fence is required to ensure that the stores and loads of `turn` in both threads agree on the order in which `turn` is written (in shared-memory).

---

**Notes on x86/x86_64**

For the x86/x86_64, for BYTE, WORD, DWORD and QWORD atomics:

1. *_release* and *_relaxed* stores are the same, and compile to simple writes.
2. *_acquire*, *_consume* and *_relaxed* loads are the same, and compile to simple reads.
3. except for *_seq_cst* all fences are the same, and compile to nothing at all.
4. *_seq_cst* fences compile to `MFENCE`.
5. all exchanges, including compare-exchanges, are *_seq_cst*, and compile to an instruction with a `LOCK` prefix (or an instruction with an implied `LOCK` prefix).
6. for *_seq_cst* loads/stores, by convention: loads compile to simple reads and stores compile to either `MOV+MFENCE` or `(LOCK) XCHG` -- for more on the convention, see below.

...provided the value is correctly aligned, or since P6 (!) does not cross a cache-line-boundary.  [Note that I use read/write to refer to the instructions which implement the load/store operations.]

So, the `lock()` with fences, for thread 0, will compile to (roughly):

```
      MOV  [flag0], $1        -- flag0.store(1, std::memory_order_relaxed)
      MOV  [turn],  $1        -- turn.store(1, std::memory_order_relaxed)
      MFENCE                  -- std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_seq_cst)
      JMP  check
    wait:                     -- while
      CALL ....               -- std::this_thread::yield()
    check:
      MOV  eax, [flag0]       -- (flag1.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)       
      TEST eax, eax
      JZ   gotit              -- have lock if !flag1
      MOV  eax, [turn]        -- (1 == turn.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)))
      CMP  eax, $1
      JZ   wait               -- must wait if turn == 1
    gotit:
```

where all the memory operations are simple read/write, and there is the one `MFENCE`.  `MFENCE` is not cheap, but is the minimum overhead required to make this thing work.

From my understanding of the x86/x86_64, I can say that the above will work.

---

**Returning to the Original Question**

The original code is not valid C++ and the result of compiling it is uncertain.

However, when compiled for x86/x86_64, it (in all probability) will in fact work.  The reasons for that are interesting.

> For those of a nervous disposition, let me be crystal clear: in what follows when I say that 'X' "works" I mean that when compiled for x86/x86_64, using the current common mechanisms to implement atomic operations on the x86/x86_64, the code generated will give the intended result.  This does not make 'X' correct C++ and certainly does not mean that it will give the intended result on other machines.

So the original code may be expected to compile to one of:

```
    # MOV+MFENCE version      |   # (LOCK) XCHG version
      MOV  [flag0], $1        |     MOV  [flag0], $1
      MOV  [turn],  $1        |     MOV  eax,  $1  
      MFENCE                  |     XCHG [turn], eax   # LOCK is implicit
      .... as above           |     .... ditto
```

and both versions work.

In the original code the `turn.exchange(1, std::memory_order_acq_rel)` will compile to the `(LOCK) XCHG` version -- making it, in fact, *_seq_cst* (because all exchanges on the  x86/x86_64 are *_seq_cst*).

NB: in general, `turn.exchange(1, std::memory_order_acq_rel)` is **not** equivalent to `turn.store(1)` -- you need `turn.exchange(1, std::memory_order_seq_cst)` for that.  It's just that on the x86/x86_64 they compile to the same thing.

For `turn.store(1)` the compiler may choose either the `MFENCE` or the `(LOCK) XCHG`  version -- they are functionally equivalent.

Now, what is required here is a store.  It's possible that the compiler will prefer the `(LOCK) XCHG` version for that (though I doubt it).  But I see no point in second guessing the compiler and forcing it to use `(LOCK) XCHG`.  [It's possible that the compiler might spot that the return value of the `turn.exchange()` is being ignored, and therefore use the `MFENCE`... but there's still no reason to second guess the compiler.]

The original question was "*Is there any reason for using 'exchange' method?*".  And the answer to that, finally (!), is no -- for the reasons given.

---

**More on x86/x86_64 and Load/Store *_seq_cst* Convention(s)**

On x86/x86_64, to store and load some variable *_seq_cst* requires either:

- an `MFENCE` (somewhere) between the write and the read of the variable.

  Conventionally, the `MFENCE` is treated as part of *_seq_cst* stores (*write+mfence*), so that a load *_seq_cst* maps to a simple read.

  Alternatively, the `MFENCE` could be treated as part of the load (*mfence+read*), but on the basis that loads tend to outnumber stores, the (significant) overhead is assigned to the stores.

or:

- a `LOCK XCHG` for the write or a `LOCK XADD $0` for the read of the variable.

  Conventionally, a `LOCK XCHG` is used for the write (*xchg-write*), so that, again, a load *_seq_cst* maps to a simple read.

  Alternatively, a `LOCK XADD $0` could be used for the load (*xadd-read*), so that a store would map to a simple write. But for the same reason as above, this is not done.

If there were no such convention, both *_seq_cst* load and store operations would have to carry the `MFENCE` or `XCHG/XADD` overhead. This would have the advantage that a *_seq_cst* load after a not-*_seq_cst* store would work -- but at significant cost.  The Standard does not require such "mixed" memory-order combinations to work, so this extra cost can be avoided. [The limitation in the Standard is not arbitrary !]

For the avoidance of doubt: it is essential that the same convention is followed throughout -- across an application, the libraries it uses and the kernel.  The *write-mfence*/*xchg-read* convention has the edge over the *mfence+read*/*xadd-read* convention, and is definitely better than no convention at all.  So, the *write-mfence*/*xchg-read* convention is the de facto standard.

[For a summary of the mapping of the simple atomic operations to instructions, for all memory-orders, for a number of common processors see https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~pes20/cpp/cpp0xmappings.html. For x86/x86_64 nearly every load/store maps to a simple read/write, and all exchanges and cmp-exchanges map to a LOCKed instruction (so are all _seq_cst). This is not true of ARM, POWERPC and others, so the correct choice of memory-order is essential.]

Comment: @[mpoeter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12747833/mpoeter): FWIW, I have thought long and hard, and I think I now have a Standard compliant version of Peterson's Algorithm.