# Are lock and unlock on the same mutex sequential consistent?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

For mutex `lock()`, the standard [mentions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/lock):

> Prior unlock() operations on the same mutex synchronize-with (as defined in std::memory_order) this operation.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15313944/1383356) tries to explain what `synchronize-with` means according to the standard. However, looks like the definition is not clearly specified.

My main question is, can I ever get this output:

```
x: 1
y: 2
```

for the following code due to memory reordering in thread A? Is the write on `x` in `A` guaranteed to be observed by `B` if `B` locks after `A` unlocks?

```
std::mutex mutex;
int x = 0, y = 0;

int main() {
  std::thread A{[] {
    x = 1;
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(std::mutex);
    y = 0;
  }};
  std::thread B{[] {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(std::mutex);
    y = x + 2;
  }};

  A.join();
  B.join();
  std::cout << "x: " << x << std::endl;
  std::cout << "y: " << y << std::endl;
}
```

If not, based on what section of the standard?
In other words, can we assume there is sequential consistency between lock/unlock?

I have also seen this [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41847511/is-stdmutex-sequentially-consistent) question but it is for separate mutexes.

Comment: Your code has UB since reads from `x` are not exclusive with writes to `x`. So no reasoning can be made about memory ordering, I don't think. Once UB is allowed, standard doesn't apply anymore. But once you fix that problem, then certainly things will be defined and `1 2` output won't be possible. 1.10/10 wouldn't hold otherwise.

Comment: If there is a race between states S1 and S2, why can't we reason about being in state S3 (i.e 1 2) or not? This question does that i think: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62164376/are-lock-and-unlock-on-the-same-mutex-sequential-consistent/62169145?noredirect=1#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The synchronize-with relation is clearly defined. The standard states the following:

> Certain library calls synchronize with other library calls performed by another thread. For example, an atomic store-release synchronizes with a load-acquire that takes its value from the store. [...] [ *Note:* The specifications of the synchronization operations define when one reads the value written by another. For atomic objects, the definition is clear. All operations on a given mutex occur in a single total order. Each mutex acquisition "reads the value written" by the last mutex release. *— end note* ]

And further:

> An atomic operation *A* that performs a release operation on an atomic object *M* synchronizes with an atomic operation *B* that performs an acquire operation on *M* and takes its value from any side effect in the release
>   sequence headed by *A*.

So in other words, if an acquire operation *A* "sees" the value stored by a release operation *B*, then *A* synchronizes-with *B*.

Consider a spin-lock where you only need a single atomic bool flag. All operations operate on that flag. In order to acquire the lock you have set the flag with an atomic read-modify-write operation. All modifications on an atomic object are totally ordered by the modification order, and it is guaranteed that a RMW operation always reads the last value (in the modification order) written before the write associated with that RMW operation.

Due to this guarantee, it is sufficient to use acquire/release semantics for the lock/unlock operations, because a successful lock operation always "sees" the value written by the previous unlock.

Regarding your question:

> Is the write on `x` in `A` guaranteed to be observed by `B` **if `B` locks after `A` unlocks**?

The important part is the "if `B` locks after `A` unlocks"! If that is guaranteed, then yes, `B`'s lock operation synchronizes-with `A`'s unlock, thereby establishing a happens-before relation. Thus `B` will observe `A`'s write. However, your code does not provide the guarantee that `B` locks after `A`, so you have a potential data race which would result in undefined behavior as correctly pointed out by @ReinstateMonica.

**Update**
The write to x is sequenced-before `A`'s unlock. It doesn't matter whether the operation is outside (before) the mutex or not. In fact, theoretically the compiler could reorder the operation so that it ends up *inside* the mutex (though this is rather unlikely). Sequenced-before is also part of the happens-before definition, so we have the following:

```
std::thread A{[] {
    x = 1; // a
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(std::mutex);
    y = 0;
    // implicit unlock: b
  }};
  std::thread B{[] {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(std::mutex); // c
    y = x + 2;
  }};
```

Assuming that `B` locks after `A` unlocks we have:

- *a* is sequenced-before *b* -> *a* happens-before *b*
- *b* synchronizes-with *c* -> *b* happens-before *c*

And since the happens-before relation is transitive it follows that *a* happens-before *c*. So yes, this is true for *all* operations that are sequenced before `A`'s unlock - regardless whether they are inside the lock or not.

Comment: Notice that A changes x before the critical section. So can we say if B locks after A, it will see all changes made by A? Both changes A makes before and inside the critical section?

Comment: Yes. I have updated my answer to make this more clear.