# Precision on std::mutex lock/unlock operation with respect to expression reordering

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, mutex

Let say I've got some `std::mutex` `Mutex` and a code like this:

```cpp
...

Mutex.lock()
expr;
Mutex.unlock()
...
```

[cppreference on unlock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/unlock) only says that an `unlock()` may synchronize with a `lock()` (which may give inter-threads synchronization relationships).
But I can find anything about compiler reordering with respect to the snippet above. Does `lock()` behave like an acquire operation and prevent `expr` to be evaluated before it?
Does `unlock()` behave like a release operation and prevent `expr` to be evaluated after it?
[this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50951011/how-does-a-mutex-lock-and-unlock-functions-prevents-cpu-reordering#:%7E:text=2-,Answers,-Sorted%20by%3A) seems to say so but seems to be specific to some implementation of mutexes.
[Another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15313296/release-acquire-semantics-wrt-stdmutex) tries to be more general but, IMHO, it's more a rather free interpretation of some parts of the standard than a *"legal"* argument.
Is there something more explicit in cppreference or, better, within the standard?

Actually, it's more than a theoretical question. In a real use case I've got a snippet like this:

```cpp
...
Mutex.lock()
expr1;
Mutex.unlock()
expr2;
...
```

And I want to be sure that `expr1` cannot be evaluated after `expr2`.

Comment: a mutex would be pretty useless if there was no guarantee that the code it was protecting would stay inside the protected block

Comment: @AlanBirtles Indeed. Yet it cannot be deduced by the simple fact that ```lock()``` will block on already locked mutex and from the synchronize with relationship (which is an interthread property). But it makes my question more academic than practical...

Comment: @AlanBirtles maybe that, as the ```lock()``` may be synchronize with a previous ```unlock()``` the compiler must leave expressions after lock(), after it, otherwise the relationship may not hold? Eventually it would be a consequence of the inter-thread property...